# Exactly when happense React state update on an unmounted component WARNING?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Exactly when should we check if a component mounted or not ???
I have a lot of `setState` call and I encounter some time with the `warning` I wrote in the **title**.

Now I can avoid this by declaring a `variable` and `initializing` to **true** in `componentDidMount` and re **asigning** to **false** on `componentWillUnmount`, and then check when `setState` gets call.

But My Exact question is, Is it necessary to check every time `setState` calls, or this warning happens in specific cicumstances ? and I should check the **variable** on that time ?

Also will affect this warning on performance?

Comment: Theoretically, any place where you load data from the component, and set the state as part of the response has the potential that the component gets dismounted in the process. I am not sure about performance issues, but having components still trying to update while they "shouldn't" exist anymore is a potential memory leak, having the check is not a bad idea

Comment: Thank you, I just dont want to check it, in every call, because if there is much `if condition then every `if` may take a time.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when you call setState asynchronously, e.g. `window.fetch().then(...setState...)` or await or inside a callback.

You could use `this.isMounted()` instead of your custom variable, but see also https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html for better solutions.